Dealing with a hole that Coq can't fill when using `pose proof`
When writing mostly-forward Coq via pose proof and friends, is there a way to either

Locally make holes more powerful so can Coq can do more to attempt to fill them in
Recursively enter a tactic context in an unfillable hole, similar to my question from four months ago, but in a tactic context not a Fixpoint definition.


Here is the full context of my question. I'm still interested in the answer to my question (assuming it isn't incoherent) even if it's a bad fit for the exact thing that I'm trying to do in this question.

I am studying this answer, and trying to prove the exercise it contains in bits and pieces.
For now, I want to show that forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l), i.e. given a hypothesis $\varphi$ that I can prove in a single step (either because $\varphi$ is an axiom or because it is an element of $\Gamma$).
Here is my proof of this theorem:
Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).   
Proof.                                                                                        
  intros.                                                                                     
  dependent destruction H.                                                                    
  - now pose proof pc_axiom G wff l H H1. 
  - now pose proof pc_in G wff l H H1.                                                        
  - simpl in H. inversion H.                                                                  
Qed.

I quite like pose proof because it is very similar to a local variable definition, albeit with strange, backwards syntax.
I especially like that pose proof something : some_type as H exists.
Anyway, using holes here sometimes works. For example, the theorem below compiles.
Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).   
Proof.    
  intros. 
  dependent destruction H. 
  - pose proof pc_axiom G wff l H H1 : proof_chain G (cons _ l) as W. easy.   
  - now pose proof pc_in G wff l H H1.                                                        
  - simpl in H. inversion H.                                                                  
Qed.

But using holes can also fail, even in cases that seem easy.
Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).   
Proof.    
  intros. 
  dependent destruction H. 
  - pose proof pc_axiom G _ _ _ H1 : proof_chain G (cons wff l) as W. easy.
  - now pose proof pc_in G wff l H H1.
  - simpl in H. inversion H.
Qed.

coqc example2.v 
File "./example2.v", line 53, characters 30-31:
Error: Cannot infer this placeholder of type "axiom wff" in
environment:
G : list formula
wff : formula
l : list formula
H : axiom wff
H0 : proof_chain G nil
H1 : proof_chain G l

I'm curious whether there's a way to either locally make holes more powerful or enter a tactic context in places where I'm calling an unfillable hole.
Appendix A
Here's the full file. I wrote almost none of it, it's lifted from this answer by Feryll.
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

Unset Printing Notations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  | pc_axiom : forall A l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_in : forall A l, In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_MP : forall A B l, In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A).

Lemma proof_chain_initial : forall Γ A l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |-- l.
Proof.
  intros.
  (* this line used to be "now dependent destruction ...".
     now just calls easy in each branch. *)
  dependent destruction H.
  - easy.
  - easy.
  - easy.
Qed.



Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).
Proof.
  intros.
  dependent destruction H.
  - pose proof pc_axiom G _ _ _ H1 : proof_chain G (cons wff l) as W. easy.
  - now pose proof pc_in G wff l H H1.
  - simpl in H. inversion H.
Qed.
```


There is unshelve epose proof ... which combines the unshelve tactical which turns evars into goals, and the epose (proof) tactic which makes everything it can't infer immediately into an evar.
The problem with that approach is that it turns everything into an evar. Usually, Coq does it more nicely where only the non-dependent premises are turned into goals, and the dependent premises become evars.
If you want a tactic that does that, but works like pose proof, I can recommend std++'s opose proof, which is basically exactly that.
With that, your last example becomes
From stdpp Require Import tactics.
Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).
Proof.
  intros.
  dependent destruction H.
  - opose proof (pc_axiom G _ _ _ _ : proof_chain G (cons wff l)) as W; easy.
  - opose proof (pc_in G _ _ _ _). 3: eassumption. all: easy.
  - simpl in H. inversion H.
Qed.

The unshelve epose variant produces similar results here, except that you still need to manually give the arguments in the second subgoal, and can not rely on evar resolution.

Does this match what you want?
Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).
Proof.
  intros.
  dependent destruction H.
  - refine (pc_axiom G _ _ _ H1).
    exact H.
  - refine (pc_in _ _ _ _ _).
    + exact H.
    + exact H1.
  - inversion H.
Qed.

Although, I personally would just do the following.

Theorem proof_chain_prepend : forall G wff l, G |-- [wff] -> G |-- l -> G |-- (cons wff l).
Proof.
  intros.
  dependent destruction H; firstorder using pc_axiom, pc_in.
Qed.


Thanks. Does this mean that the way to delay filling in _ in a hypothesis is to use assert + refine?

I'm not really sure what it means to delay a hypothesis. A hypothesis, by definition, is something that you already have. An "incomplete hypothesis" doesn't make sense to me.
